# Does the OBDII work (Receive commands and send responses) even with the vehicle's engine off?

Tags: obd-ii

Why does my OBDII (Bluetooth adapter) generate a response (for example, using PID command 0105 among others) even when the vehicle's engine is off?

It is expected that when the vehicle's engine is off the response would be NO DATA or something similar... but in the OBDII v 1.5 that I am using this does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Most commands do not require the engine actually running, but only ignition being on. This behavior is not standardized in OBD2 though, it's vendor specific.